# After scrolling listview, listview items getting repeatedly in android

Tags: android

In my project,While clicking on grid view items, i need to add that in list view, So it to be a dynamic one.But After adding 8 to 9 items list view showing items repeatedly on scroll.

```
public class ProductCartCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
private int mPosition;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
public LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSelectedProductId = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
private HashMap<String, String> mSelectedProductCustom = new HashMap<String, String>();
private Bitmap scaledBitmap;
private int count = 0;
private int countCustom = 0;
public static Integer mQuantity;
public static String mSubTotalamount, mTaxAmount, mTotalAmounttext,
        mDiscountAmountString, mCurrencySymbol;
public static float mTotalAmount = 0;
public static HashMap<Integer, List<String>> mSelectedProductId1 = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
private List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
private String mProductId;
// inside your custom Adapter

public static HashMap<String, Integer> mPidarrayList = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
public static HashMap<String, Integer> mQtyarrayList = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
public static HashMap<String, Integer> mDiscountarrayList = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
public static HashMap<String, Integer> mTaxarrayList = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

private static final int REGULAR = 0;
private static final int HEADER = 1;


// Constructor
public ProductCartCustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int pos,
        ArrayList<String> arrayList2,
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSelectedProductId,
        HashMap<String, String> mSelectedProductCustom,
        HashMap<Integer, List<String>> mSelectedProductId1,
        HashMap<String, Integer> mPidarrayList,
        HashMap<String, Integer> mQtyarrayList,
        HashMap<String, Integer> mDiscountarrayList,
        HashMap<String, Integer> mTaxarrayList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context = applicationContext;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    this.mPosition = pos;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;

    this.mSelectedProductId = mSelectedProductId;
    this.mSelectedProductCustom = mSelectedProductCustom;
    this.mSelectedProductId1 = mSelectedProductId1;
    this.mPidarrayList = mPidarrayList;
    this.mQtyarrayList = mQtyarrayList;
    this.mDiscountarrayList = mDiscountarrayList;
    this.mTaxarrayList = mTaxarrayList;

    mTotalAmount = 0;

    // create a instance of SQLite Database
    loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(context);
    loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

    Cursor cursor10 = loginDataBaseAdapter.RetrieveStoreInfo();
    if (cursor10 != null && cursor10.moveToFirst()) {

        mCurrencySymbol = cursor10.getString(cursor10
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("CURRENCY_SYMBOL"));

    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mSelectedProductId.size() + mSelectedProductCustom.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

// Binding the values fetch from arraylist
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder mViewHolder = null;
    String mProductTitle_Json = null, mProductPrice_Json = null;
    byte[] mProductImage_Json = null;


    if (convertView == null) {
        // convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_products, null);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cartlistviewitems, null);

        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        mViewHolder.tvAmount = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.CartItemAmount);
        mViewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.CartItemName);
        mViewHolder.tvCartItemDiscount = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.CartItemDiscount);
        mViewHolder.tvCartItemTax = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.CartItemTax);
        mViewHolder.tvProductId = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ProductId);
        mViewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.CartItemImage);
        mViewHolder.ivQtyIcon = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.CartQuantityImage);
        mViewHolder.Layout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.productcart_listview_row_layout);

        mViewHolder.tvCurrencySymbol = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.currencysymbol);

        mViewHolder.tvCartItemDiscount.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {

        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // List out the Product name , Quantity, Amount, Discount and Tax in
    // list view
    if ((count + countCustom) < mSelectedProductId.size()
            + mSelectedProductCustom.size()) {

        if (mSelectedProductId != null && mSelectedProductId.size() > 0
                && count < mSelectedProductId.size()) {

            System.out.println("*************************************");

            // System.out.println("mPos adapter: " + mPosition);

            // Copy the Products keyset and values in List
            List<Integer> lstProductId = new ArrayList<Integer>(
                    mSelectedProductId.keySet());
            List<Integer> lstQuantity = new ArrayList<Integer>(
                    mSelectedProductId.values());

            List<Integer> lstPId = new ArrayList<Integer>(
                    mPidarrayList.values());
            List<Integer> lstQty = new ArrayList<Integer>(
                    mQtyarrayList.values());

            List<Integer> lstDiscount = new ArrayList<Integer>(
                    mDiscountarrayList.values());
            List<Integer> lstTax = new ArrayList<Integer>(
                    mTaxarrayList.values());

            mQuantity = lstQty.get(count);



            Cursor cursor = loginDataBaseAdapter
                    .RetrieveProductInfoEntry(String.valueOf(lstPId
                            .get(count)));

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                mProductImage_Json = cursor.getBlob(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow("PRODUCT_IMAGE"));
                mProductTitle_Json = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow("PRODUCT_TITLE"));
                mProductPrice_Json = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow("PRICE"));
                mProductId = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow("PRODUCT_ID"));

            // Scaling the image
                if (mProductImage_Json != null
                        && mProductImage_Json.length != 0) {
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inSampleSize = 3;
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                            mProductImage_Json, 0,
                            mProductImage_Json.length);
                    scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 25, 25,
                            true);

                    String Qty = String.valueOf(mQuantity);
                    try {
                        mViewHolder.ivIcon.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
                        mViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(mProductTitle_Json);
                        mViewHolder.tvProductId.setText(mProductId);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Float amt = Float.parseFloat(mProductPrice_Json);

                    float mAmount = mQuantity * amt;
                    // String Amount1 = String.valueOf(mAmount);
                    String amount = new DecimalFormat("##.##")
                            .format(mAmount);

                    int k = lstProductId.size();
                    int l = count;
                    int p = k - l;

                    // Method for Special Discount for particular Item
                    try {
                        if (!(lstDiscount.get(count) == 0)
                                && lstDiscount.get(count) != null) {

                            String Discount = lstDiscount.get(count)
                                    .toString();

                            mViewHolder.tvCartItemDiscount
                                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mViewHolder.tvCartItemDiscount.setText(Discount
                                    + "%");

                        loat floatValue1 = Float.parseFloat(Discount);

                            float mProductDiscountAmount = mAmount
                                    * (floatValue1 / 100);

                        mAmount = mAmount - mProductDiscountAmount;

                            amount = new DecimalFormat("##.##")
                                    .format(mAmount);

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out
                                .println("Product Custom Adapter Spl Dis: "
                                        + e);
                    }

                    // Method for Special Tax for particular Item
                    try {

                        // if (lstTax.get(p - 1) == 1) {
                        if (lstTax.get(count) == 1) {

                            float mVatpercentage = Float
                                    .parseFloat(Product.mVatPercentage);

                            Double mTaxamount = (double) (mAmount * (mVatpercentage / 100));
                            mTaxAmount = new DecimalFormat("##.##")
                                    .format(mTaxamount);

                            mAmount = (float) (mAmount - Float
                                    .parseFloat(mTaxAmount));

                            amount = new DecimalFormat("##.##")
                                    .format(mAmount);

                            mViewHolder.tvCartItemTax
                                    .setText("Tax not applicable");

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out
                                .println("Product Custom Adapter Spl tax error: "
                                        + e);
                    }

                    try {
                        mViewHolder.tvAmount.setText(amount);
                        mViewHolder.ivQtyIcon.setText(Qty);
                        mViewHolder.tvCurrencySymbol
                                .setText(mCurrencySymbol);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    mTotalAmount = mTotalAmount + Float.parseFloat(amount);
                    mSubTotalamount = new DecimalFormat("##.##")
                            .format(mTotalAmount);

                // Method for Special Discount for All Items
                    if (Product.mDiscountPercentageString != null
                            && !Product.mDiscountPercentageString.isEmpty()) {

                        float floatValue1 = Float
                                .parseFloat(ProductCartCustomAdapter.mSubTotalamount);
                        float floatValue2 = Float
                                .parseFloat(Product.mDiscountPercentageString);

                        float mProductDiscountAmount = floatValue1
                                * (floatValue2 / 100);

                        ProductCartCustomAdapter.mDiscountAmountString = new DecimalFormat(
                                "##.##").format(mProductDiscountAmount);

                        Product.mDiscountAmount_tv.setText(mCurrencySymbol
                                + mDiscountAmountString);

                        float mTotalAmount1 = floatValue1
                                - mProductDiscountAmount;
                        float mVatpercentage = Float
                                .parseFloat(Product.mVatPercentage);

                        // Calculate the Tax
                        Double mTaxamount = (double) (mTotalAmount1 * (mVatpercentage / 100));
                        mTaxAmount = new DecimalFormat("##.##")
                                .format(mTaxamount);

                        Double mTotal = mTaxamount + mTotalAmount1;
                        mTotalAmounttext = new DecimalFormat("##.##")
                                .format(mTotal);
                    }
                    // Else part of the Discount for all product cart
                    else {
                        float mVatpercentage = Float
                                .parseFloat(Product.mVatPercentage);

                        Double mTaxamount = (double) (mTotalAmount * (mVatpercentage / 100));
                        mTaxAmount = new DecimalFormat("##.##")
                                .format(mTaxamount);

                        // System.out.println("Amount Tax : " +
                        // mTaxAmount);

                        Double mTotal = mTaxamount + mTotalAmount;
                        mTotalAmounttext = new DecimalFormat("##.##")
                                .format(mTotal);
                    }

                    Product.mSubTotal_tv.setText("");
                    Product.mSubTotal_tv
                            .setText(ProductCartCustomAdapter.mSubTotalamount);
                    Product.mVatPercent_textview.setText("("
                            + Product.mVatPercentage + ")" + "%");
                    Product.mTaxAmount_tv.setText(mCurrencySymbol
                            + ProductCartCustomAdapter.mTaxAmount);

                    Product.mTotalAmount_tv.setText(mCurrencySymbol
                            + ProductCartCustomAdapter.mTotalAmounttext);

                    int CartQuantity1 = mSelectedProductCustom.size();
                    int CartQuantity2 = mSelectedProductId.size();
                    int CartQuantity3 = CartQuantity1 + CartQuantity2;

                    Product.mCartNumber_tv.setText("Cart(" + CartQuantity3
                            + ")");

                }
            }
            cursor.close();
            count++;
        }

        // Custom Cart Sale Method to display
        else if (count >= mSelectedProductId.size()) {
            // && countCustom < mSelectedProductCustom.size()
            if (mSelectedProductCustom != null
                    && mSelectedProductCustom.size() > 0) {

                List<String> lstProductId = new ArrayList<String>(
                        mSelectedProductCustom.keySet());
                List<String> lstProductId1 = lstProductId;
                List<String> lstQuantity = new ArrayList<String>(
                        mSelectedProductCustom.values());
                List<String> lstQuantity2 = lstQuantity;

                String ss = lstQuantity.get(countCustom);
                // System.out.println("ss custom :" + ss);
                String[] separated = ss.split("\\|");
                String amount = separated[0];
                String qty = separated[1];

                // System.out.println("a custom: " + amount);
                // System.out.println("b custom: " + qty);

                Float amt = Float.parseFloat(amount);
                int mQty = Integer.parseInt(qty);
                float mAmount = mQty * amt;
                // String Amount1 = String.valueOf(mAmount);
                String amount1 = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(mAmount);

                mViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(lstProductId.get(countCustom));
                mViewHolder.tvAmount.setText(mCurrencySymbol + amount1);
                mViewHolder.ivQtyIcon.setText(qty);

                // System.out.println("mDiscountPercentageString : "+
                // Product.mDiscountPercentageString);

                // Method for Special Discount for All Items
                if (Product.mDiscountPercentageString != null
                        && !Product.mDiscountPercentageString.isEmpty()
                        && Float.parseFloat(Product.mDiscountPercentageString) > 0) {
                    // System.out.println("mSubTotalamount 1: "
                    // + ProductCartCustomAdapter.mSubTotalamount);
                    float subtotal = Float
                            .parseFloat(ProductCartCustomAdapter.mSubTotalamount);
                    if (amount1 != null && !amount1.isEmpty()) {

                        subtotal = Float
                                .parseFloat(ProductCartCustomAdapter.mSubTotalamount)
                                + Float.parseFloat(amount1);
                        ProductCartCustomAdapter.mSubTotalamount = String
                                .valueOf(subtotal);
                    }
                    // System.out.println("mSubTotalamount 2 - Discount: "
                    // + ProductCartCustomAdapter.mSubTotalamount);
                    ProductCartCustomAdapter.mSubTotalamount = new DecimalFormat(
                            "##.##").format(subtotal);

                    Product.mSubTotal_tv
                            .setText(ProductCartCustomAdapter.mSubTotalamount);

                    float floatValue1 = Float
                            .parseFloat(ProductCartCustomAdapter.mSubTotalamount);
                    float floatValue2 = Float
                            .parseFloat(Product.mDiscountPercentageString);

                    float mProductDiscountAmount = floatValue1
                            * (floatValue2 / 100);

                    mDiscountAmountString = new DecimalFormat("##.##")
                            .format(mProductDiscountAmount);

                    Product.mDiscountAmount_tv.setText("");
                    Product.mDiscountAmount_tv
                            .setText(mDiscountAmountString);

                    mTotalAmount = floatValue1 - mProductDiscountAmount;

                }

                float m = Float.parseFloat(amount1);


                // Adding Total amount and particular amount on Item
                mTotalAmount = mTotalAmount + m;

                ProductCartCustomAdapter.mSubTotalamount = new DecimalFormat(
                        "##.##").format(mTotalAmount);

                Product.mSubTotal_tv
                        .setText(ProductCartCustomAdapter.mSubTotalamount);

                // Calculate Tax
                float mVatpercentage = Float
                        .parseFloat(Product.mVatPercentage);

                Double mTaxamount = (double) (mTotalAmount * (mVatpercentage / 100));
                mTaxAmount = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(mTaxamount);

                // Adding subtotal and tax

                Double mTotal = mTaxamount + mTotalAmount;
                mTotalAmounttext = new DecimalFormat("##.##")
                        .format(mTotal);

                // System.out.println("Amount tot : " +
                // mTotalAmounttext);
                Product.mVatPercent_textview.setText("("
                        + Product.mVatPercentage + ")" + "%");

                Product.mTaxAmount_tv.setText(mCurrencySymbol
                        + ProductCartCustomAdapter.mTaxAmount);

                Product.mTotalAmount_tv.setText(mCurrencySymbol
                        + ProductCartCustomAdapter.mTotalAmounttext);

                int CartQuantity1 = mSelectedProductCustom.size();
                int CartQuantity2 = mSelectedProductId.size();
                int CartQuantity3 = CartQuantity1 + CartQuantity2;

                Product.mCartNumber_tv.setText("Cart(" + CartQuantity3
                        + ")");

                countCustom++;
            }
        }
    }

    // loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    return convertView;
}

// Holder Class
private class ViewHolder {
    public RelativeLayout Layout;
    TextView tvTitle, tvAmount, ivQtyIcon, tvTotalAmount, mTaxAmount_tv,
            mSubTotal_tv, mTotalAmount_tv, tvProductId, tvCurrencySymbol,
            tvCartItemDiscount, tvCartItemTax;
    ImageView ivIcon;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you using your "position" in the getView code?you query your products outside the getView, getview should only be concerned about the  product with index "position"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try overloading the following two functions in your ProductCartCustomAdapter class:

```
getItemViewType()

getViewTypeCount()
```

after overloading they may look like :

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return getCount();
}
```

hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: Superb . Its working perfectly yar. thank you very much dude.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ViewHolder but not in a proper way,

When you do `convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);`
You have to tell view holder that which tag corresponds to which id by doing 
i.e `convertView.setTag(R.id.yourtextviewID, viewHolder.textView);` for each and every widget you have used after `convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);` line,

Now the important part is after you do

```
else {

        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

you also have to set the tags to thier correct positions so the items may appear properly

```
viewHolder.textView.setTag(position);
```

for each and every widget you use
Your ViewHolder is not a static class,in general viewholders are static class

```
static class ViewHolder
```

everything else is correct, no need to do `notifyDatasetChanged`

Comment: How to set , viewHolder.textView.setTag(position); in adapter . Because in this program i need to calculate the amount * quantity, subtotal, vat and Total.

Comment: Cursor cursor = loginDataBaseAdapter
                    .RetrieveProductInfoEntry(String.valueOf(lstPId
                            .get(count)));    After fetch the values from cursor, based upon that only i can assign the values in views, Then how can i set value using position.

Comment: You are just setting tags using positions, not the values, so dont worry about it, from your code, you have to set it like,  mViewHolder.tvAmount.setTag(position);, for each and every widget, Simple!

Comment: Where i need to set that .. After else part, or inside (Converview ==  null){ }..

Comment: just after the else bracket over  , as stated in answer,

Comment: msj003 Given a correct answer . Thank you friends for your support.

Answer (score -1):

try calling youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after you are adding/deleting

Comment: Ya, After adding or deleting  called that too dude.But nothing happens